# Visual Studio 2013 not retaining the selection of Typescript project settings

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to turn on the automatic compile on save option for my typescript files. I am using VS 2013 ( cannot use any other version ) ,navigating to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Typescript ->Project -> General and I am checking the options "Automatically compile Typescript files which are not part of a project" under 'Compile on Save' .

However when I hit ok and then re-open the above setting again , I see that VS is not saving my changes and resetting it to the old unchecked value.

I am running VS in Admin Mode. 
tsc -v on my console shows Version 2.5.3 
I have Web essentials 2.6.13.0 installed

Could someone please help me with what I am missing? [Screen shot of setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkw2j.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following steps fixed my problem.

1. Applied Visual Studio 2013 Update 5
2. Changed the PATH environment variable to point to 1.8 Typescript . Was pointing to 1.0 earlier.
   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8)

3.Deleted the 1.0 Typescript folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\